# What's the easiest way to pass data between two simultaneously displayed view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller, closures

I'm getting in a muddle trying to pass data between two viewcontrollers that are displayed on one screen via container views.

Minimal example below - top view (TopVC) has a textInput field. When I press the button, I want the label on the bottom view (BottomVC) to display the inputted text. Moreover, I want it to pass back a message to the TopVC and update the topVC label with the message "Successfully contacted bottom VC"

**Storyboard set up**

[image: Screen Shot]

I have no idea now to reference the view controllers from each other basically.

```
class TopViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textOutput: UILabel!

    @IBAction func go(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // ??????????? 
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    func callMeBaby(greeting: String) {
        textOutput.text = greeting
    }
}
```

In the **?????** placeholder, I want to put something that basically works like BottomVC.test(textInput.text, callmebaby) - but obviously I need to put in some extra code to 'introduce' the two ViewControllers, and I'm not sure what to do.

```
class BottomViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }

    func test(input: String, completion: (String) -> Void) {
        textLabel.text = input
        completion("Successfully contacted bottom VC")
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36530453/1630618

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Creating Delegates

Start with creating delegates for both of your container ViewControllers. Don't forget to add `: class`. If you didn't do it, you wouldn't be able to create *weak* delegate variable:

```
protocol TopViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func sendMessage(_ string: String)
}
protocol BottomViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func sendMessage(_ string: String)
}
```

Now for every container ViewController create *weak* delegate variable

```
class TopViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: TopViewControllerDelegate?
    ...
}

class BottomViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: BottomViewControllerDelegate?
    ...
}
```

then for TopVC implement Bottom's delegate and for BottomVC Top's.

```
extension TopViewController: BottomViewControllerDelegate {
    func sendMessage(_ string: String) {
        // do something
    }
}
extension BottomViewController: TopViewControllerDelegate {
    func sendMessage(_ string: String) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

#### Assigning Delegates

Your segues between main ViewController and containers should have their own identifiers: `EmbedTop`, `EmbedBottom`.

So in your `WrapperViewController` create variable for your Top and Bottom ViewController and override method `prepare(for:sender:)` and inside assign these variables

```
class WrapperViewController: UIViewController {

    var topVC: TopViewController?
    var bottomVC: BottomViewController?

    ...

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "EmbedTop" {
            topVC = segue.destination as! TopViewController
        } else if segue.identifier == "EmbedBottom" {
            bottomVC = segue.destination as! BottomViewController
        }
    }

}
```

finally in `viewDidAppear` set delegate of TopVC's as BottomVC and of BottomVC's as TopVC

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    topVC.delegate = bottomVC
    bottomVC.delegate = topVC
}
```

Now your two ViewControllers can speak with each other! :-)

---

*Example:*

```
class BottomViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    func speakToTop() {
        delegate?.sendMessage("Hi Top!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice and idiomatic answer ;) I would just add a `weak` qualifier to each `delegate` property declaration to avoid unnecessary *retention cycles* (between the nested view controllers).

Comment: @PauloMattos thank you, I'm young and still a beginner, so I'm always glad for responses like this! If I made `delegate` properites `weak`, then I would have to add `: class` to  protocol declaring, right?

Comment: Yep, good catch! Weak properties *only* make sense for reference types (and adding `class` to your protocol declaration ensures just that).

Comment: @PauloMattos. adding class to protocol declaration makes it a reference type so that weak can be applied ?

Comment: Thank you! Note for the terminally dim (like me: make sure your segues identifiers in storyboard match what you're calling in the code!!!)