# How can I use segmented control from container view to control my main view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a quiz app. I have parent table view controller that handles  everything but segmented control and child container view with scrollable segmented control. I can't quite understand how I connect parent and child view controllers so I can use segmented control to change questions.

I've tried to use this code in child vc file, but it doesn't give me options to equate segment index to question number variable in parent vc.

```swift
class ScrollSegmentVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
@IBAction func segmentPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
            print(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        if let firstVC = parent as? FirstTableViewController {
        ...    
        }
    }
```

**1**

[image: Screen Shot1]

**2**

[image: Screen Shot2]

UPDATE. I Used delegate method as was proposed. Everything worked out, but now I can't pass data back to container view.

```swift
protocol ScrollSegmentDelegate {
    func segmentIsChosen(segment: Int)
}

class ScrollSegmentVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    var delegate: ScrollSegmentDelegate?
    var questionNumberToReceive = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func segmentPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let segment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        delegate?.segmentIsChosen(segment: segment)
        print("scroll:\(questionNumberToReceive)")
    }
```

```swift
class FirstTestTableViewController: UITableViewController, ScrollSegmentDelegate {

    func segmentIsChosen(segment: Int) {
        print(segment)
        questionNumber = segment + 1
}

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {        
        if segue.identifier == "segment" {
            let destSegmentVC = segue.destination as! ScrollSegmentVC
            destSegmentVC.questionNumberToReceive = questionNumber
            destSegmentVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

and wherever I'm calling segue

```swift
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segment", sender: self)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'There are unexpected subviews in the container view. Perhaps the embed segue has already fired once or a subview was added programmatically?'
```

If I don't call segue at some point - I'm not getting updated variables

Comment: Rather then using `parent` property use delegate pattern or closures.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36531234/1630618) demonstrates the use of delegates with embedded viewControllers.  You need to give the embedding segue an "identifier" so that `FirstTableViewController` can set the delegate pointer in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I followed your suggestions, but got another problem I described in "UPDATE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution for this.

```swift
class FirstTestTableViewController: UITableViewController, ScrollSegmentDelegate {

    func segmentIsChosen(segment: Int) {
        print(segment)
        questionNumber = segment + 1
}

var questionNumber = 0

func updateQuestionNumber() {
questionNumber + 1
 scrollSegmentVC?.questionNumberToReceive = questionNumber
}

 var scrollSegmentVC: ScrollSegmentVC?

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {        
        if segue.identifier == "segment" {
            scrollSegmentVC = segue.destination as? ScrollSegmentVC
            scrollSegmentVC?.delegate = self
        }
    }
```